# Camel : ClassCastException: DefaultMessage cannot be cast to class SnmpMessage

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, apache-camel, junit5

I'm getting the following ClassCastException from a unit test when I try to call `testTemplate.sendBody(String, Object)` below:

**SnmpRoute.kt**

```
.process { exchange ->
    val message = exchange.getIn() as SnmpMessage
```

**SnmpRouteTest.kt**

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner::class)
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisableJmx(false)
@MockEndpoints("log:*")
class SnmpRouteTest {

    object SnmpConstants {
        const val SNMP_TRAP = "<snmp><entry><oid>1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0</oid><value>6 days, 3:44:57.82</value></entry><entry><oid>1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0</oid><value>1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.0.1</value></entry><entry><oid>1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1</oid><value>123456</value></entry></snmp>"
    }

    @Autowired
    lateinit var camelContext: CamelContext

    @Produce
    lateinit var testTemplate: ProducerTemplate

    ...
    ...

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun testSnmpRoute() {

        AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(camelContext, "CamelSnmpTrapRoute") { routeBuilder -> routeBuilder.replaceFromWith(SnmpConstants.DIRECT_SNMP_ENDPOINT) }

        testTemplate.sendBody(SnmpConstants.DIRECT_SNMP_ENDPOINT, SnmpConstants.SNMP_TRAP)

        ...
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.camel.support.DefaultMessage cannot be cast to class 
org.apache.camel.component.snmp.SnmpMessage (org.apache.camel.support.DefaultMessage and org.apache.
camel.component.snmp.SnmpMessage are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I have tried to construct an `SnmpMessage` object and use that in the `sendBody()` call, as when I test this route manually with the `snmptrap` utility, I see the following in the logs:

```
Get In[SnmpMessage: <snmp><entry><oid>1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0</oid><value>12 days, 8:40:47.70</value></entry><entry><oid>1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0</oid><value>1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.0.1</value></entry><entry><oid>1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1</oid><value>123456</value></entry></snmp>]
```

However I'm getting the same issue with this approach.

I am using Apache Camel `v3.0.0-RC3`

Thanks to @ShellDragon for help so far with this.

Comment: I see Claus Ibsen's answer sufficiently explanatory. Did you manage to crack it already?

Comment: @ShellDragon : I did, eventually.  Posted it below as an answer.  Thanks for all your help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.  I needed to overwrite the `exchange.getIn()` message with an `SnmpMessage`, and add a `PDU` object, rather than the XML String block.

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = [SnmpTrapReceiverApplication::class])
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisableJmx(false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class SnmpTrapRouteTest {

    @MockBean
    lateinit var repo: PojoRepo

    @Produce
    lateinit var producerTemplate: ProducerTemplate

    @Autowired
    lateinit var camelContext: CamelContext

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun testSnmpRoute() {

        AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(camelContext, "snmp-trap-route") { routeBuilder ->
            routeBuilder.replaceFromWith("direct:snmp-from")
        }

        // Create a PDU object to send to the SNMP endpoint, rather than SNMP XML
        val trap = PDU()
        trap.type = PDU.TRAP
        trap.requestID = Integer32(123456789)
        trap.add(VariableBinding(OID("1.2.3.4.5"), OctetString("snmp-trap-payload")))

        // Create a new DefaultExchange and add an SnmpMessage object as the in-message,
        // constructed with the camelContext and the PDU object
        val exchange = DefaultExchange(camelContext)
        exchange.setIn(SnmpMessage(camelContext, trap))
        producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:snmp-from")
        producerTemplate.send(exchange)

        verify(repo, atLeast(1)).save(any())
    }
}
```

Since I am using JUnit 5, I changed `@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner::class)` to `@CamelSpringBootTest`, as after downloading the `3.0.0-RC3` release source, I found a comment saying to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor is casting to a SmppMessage, but your unit test, replaces the consumer (from endpoint) from a smpp to direct component and therefore the message implementation is DefaultMessage.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the info @ClausIbsen.  Helped point me in the right direction!